# How can I set a dynamic className on a model(parse object) using parse.com with backbonejs

Tags: backbone.js, parse-platform

Basically I have a model/collection that I want to reuse.  I have a couple different collections on parse.com 'https://api.parse.com/1/classes/foo' and 'https://api.parse.com/1/classes/bar'.

**My Collection:**

```
    define([
    "app",

    "models/listModel",

], function (app, ListModel) {
    var ListCollection = Parse.Collection.extend({

        model: ListModel,

    });

    return ListCollection;
});
```

**My Model:**

```
    define([
    "app"
],
function(app) {

    var ListModel = Parse.Object.extend({

        className: null,

        initialize: function(attrs, options) {
            this.className = app.foobar ? 'foo' : 'bar';
        }

    });

    return ListModel;

});
```

**And then I create a new collection:**

```
app.foobar = 'bar';

var collection = new ListCollection();

collection.fetch({
    wait: true,
    success: function(collection, response, error) {
        console.log(collection);
    }
});
```

**And this is the error I get:**

```
Uncaught Error: Parse.Object.extend's first argument should be the className.
```

That gets thrown before initialize is ever fired in the model.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't seem to work either. I get the same error as before.

Comment: Have you read the [Parse.Object documentation](https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#objects-classes)? Seems that `extend` is supposed to have a string as the first argument...

Comment: @muistooshort Yep and they say alternatively you can use the typical backbone syntax.  

(I can NOT seem to get the code syntax to work for this comment)  

// Alternatively, you can use the typical Backbone syntax.  
var Achievement = Parse.Object.extend({  
    className: "Achievement"  
});

Comment: Do you have the latest version of the parse.com libraries? Perhaps the `className: ...` option was added later. In any case, it seems to want to know the `className` when `extend`ing, not when instantiating so `className: app.foobar ? 'foo' : 'bar'` might be an option.

Comment: Yep, that worked.  Not sure why I didn't think to try that.  Thanks!

Comment: @muistooshort actually it doesn't work.  I'm using requirejs and if I set app.foobar before my collection and models get loaded for the first time it works but updating it and then creating a new collection (new ListCollection()) the value is the same as it was when it was first loaded.